# UIButton no action when click swift 3 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

i have a problem with my custom UIButton. When I add a target, there is no action performed when I click. I tried to move function into ViewController class, change selector name and type, in vain.
There is my code. Hope you can help me.
(Hierarchy)
CustomButton → MenuButtonGroup → ViewController

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

/** vue 1 */
private let view1 = UIImageView()

/** vue 2 */
private let view2 = UIView()

/** couleur du bouton */
private var color = ""

/** décalage y pour le 3d */
private let relief = screenHeight*0.013


init(frame: CGRect, color: String){
    super.init(frame: frame)


    self.color = color
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    //définir la couleur de l'ombre
    switch color {
    case "red":
        self.backgroundColor = shadowRedColor
    case "green":
        self.backgroundColor = shadowGreenColor
    case "blue":
        self.backgroundColor = shadowBlueColor
    case "yellow":
        self.backgroundColor = shadowYellowColor
    default:
        self.backgroundColor = shadowRedColor
    }

    mainColorView()

self.addSubview(view2)

    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(downAction), for: .touchDown)
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUp), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUp), for: .touchUpOutside)

}

/** vue de couleur principale*/
func mainColorView(){

    view2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -relief, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
    view2.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    //définir la couleur de l'ombre
    switch color {
    case "red":
        view2.backgroundColor = redColor
    case "green":
        view2.backgroundColor = greenColor
    case "blue":
        view2.backgroundColor = blueColor
    case "yellow":
        view2.backgroundColor = yellowColor
    default:
        view2.backgroundColor = redColor
    }
}

/** appuis sur le bouton */
func downAction(sender: UIButton){
    print("prout")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.view2.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.relief)
    })
}

/**relacher le bouton*/
func touchUp(){
    animUp()
}

/** animer le relachement du bouton*/
func animUp(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.3, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.view2.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    })
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Adding the button to MenuButtonGroup :

```
playButton = CustomButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300), color: "green")
```

The button is showed on screen but no action at all. I tried bringSubviewToFront but with no effect.

Comment: Have you tried to `addTarget` to it?

Comment: Yes, it's in shared code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding the so called `view2` to your `UIButton`, your are setting it up to be the same size as the button with this:

```
view2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -relief, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
```

This means, that the `view2` covers the whole button beneath and it swallows the touch events from your button. Do the following:

```
view2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

And life will be all good.

**EDIT:**

After looking at your project, it is clear, that you are adding this button to a `UIImageView` as a subview. The problem is still kind of the same, by default, `UIImageView` `isUserInteractionEnabled` is set to `false`.

So, make sure, you set it to `true` in the initialiser of `MenuButtonGroup`.

```
self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

So, disable user interaction for the `UIView` instance, and enable user interaction for the `UIImageView` subclass.

And life will be even better.

Comment: I would like to say that it works, but even if I do not add view2 to my view and / or isUserInteractionEnabled = false, the action does not happen

Comment: Can you please try to download my project ? May be the error is in other file , there is juste 5 smalls files : (500ko) http : / / we.tl/rMCasf0f8e

Comment: When I add my CustomButton to ViewController view, it's work. But my CustomButton is in one view which is added to ViewController. I tried to add isUserInteractionEnabled to it, but still not work. But thanks we progress !

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I know it now. You save me ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning incorrect action.

Your action declaration is `func downAction(sender: UIButton)`, however you are adding `func downAction()`. You need to add it like this:

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(downAction(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
```

Comment: @MatthieuBravo probably `view2` blocks the touches. Try to add action to it. `view2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(downAction(sender:)), for: .touchDown)`.

Comment: Still no react. I can't see where is the problem.

Comment: @MatthieuBravo with correct action assigned it works. There is a problem with your layout - only top left quarter of the button responds to touches. Try tapping on the top left corner.

Comment: @MaxPevser With your answers and tapping on the top left corner, I can't see any action. view2 = UIButton, addTarget to view2, adding view2 to CustomButton.

Comment: @MaxPevser can you download my project (500ko) ? http : / / we.tl/rMCasf0f8e

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
init(frame: CGRect, color: String) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.color = color
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    //définir la couleur de l'ombre
    switch color {
    case "red":
        self.backgroundColor = shadowRedColor
    case "green":
        self.backgroundColor = shadowGreenColor
    case "blue":
        self.backgroundColor = shadowBlueColor
    case "yellow":
        self.backgroundColor = shadowYellowColor
    default:
        self.backgroundColor = shadowRedColor
    }    

    mainColorView()

    self.addSubview(view2)

    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(downAction), for: .touchDown)
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUp), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUp), for: .touchUpOutside)
}
```

To this:

```
init(frame: CGRect, color: String) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.color = color
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    //définir la couleur de l'ombre
    switch color {
        case "red":
             self.backgroundColor = shadowRedColor
        case "green":
             self.backgroundColor = shadowGreenColor
        case "blue":
             self.backgroundColor = shadowBlueColor
        case "yellow":
             self.backgroundColor = shadowYellowColor
        default:
             self.backgroundColor = shadowRedColor
    }

    mainColorView()

    self.view2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomButton.downAction), for: .touchDown)
    self.view2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomButton.touchUp), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomButton.touchUp), for: .touchUpOutside)

    self.addSubview(view2)
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Try do delete sender: UIButton from function definition:

```
func downAction() {
    print("prout")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.view2.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.relief)
    })
}
```

**EDIT2:**
Try to change view2 type from `UIView()` to `UIButton()`

Comment: @MatthieuBravo are u sure that u r adding subview after added targets now?

Comment: No change, still does not react.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, no action.

Comment: @MatthieuBravo check upate

Comment: Nothing change at all

Comment: @MatthieuBravo try to change view2 type from UIView to UIButton

Comment: It was like that before. I've changed to see if it does not block.

Comment: There is the link to the project if you want to look closer. It's a test project, http : / / we.tl/rMCasf0f8e